# Converting a range of numbers to an array while keeping leading zeroes

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, range

I have the following function

```
$group_extensions = '001-008';
$result = preg_replace_callback('/(\d+)-(\d+)/', function($m) {
    return implode(',', range($m[1], $m[2]));
}, $group_extensions);
```

Which convert the array of numbers to an array with every numbers in between, I which to have an output like the following :

```
001,002,003,004,005,006,007,008
```

But instead it strips all the leadings zeroes, like that

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

I wonder how to achieve that, the numbers in the array won't always have the same length so it could be 0001-0008 or 01-08.

Comment: Use `sprint()` when you echo the values

Comment: Thanks, Will try to figure out with that, my concern is that when I do the echo, I must know how many leading zeroes to input, but I do not know, since the group_extension array could contain any given numbers.

Comment: The length of the max value will tell you how long you need to set the mask for sprintf